# Unexpected modification of a Python 3 list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am new to coding and was trying solve a question on here posed previously. Have a list (lst) of dictionaries. Want to create a new list (newlist) of dictionaries, with the count of identical dictionaries in the original list, in new list as keyed item in each dictionary. My code below adds the count of dictionaries to dictionary of **original** list and I can't see why.

```
lst = [{'time': 10, 'stuff': 'abcd'},{'time': 10, 'stuff':'abcd'},{'time': 11, 'stuff': 'bcd'},{'time': 12, 'stuff': 'dc'},{'time': 13, 'stuff': 'ak'},{'time': 11, 'stuff': 'bcd'}]
newlist= []
m = 0
while len(lst)>0 :
    y = lst[0]
    ycount = lst.count(y)
    newlist=newlist + [y]
    newlist[m]['count'] = ycount
    print(f'lst = {lst}\n')
    while y in lst:
        lst.remove(y)
    m += 1
print(f'newlist= {newlist}')
```

Comment: can you provide sample output.

Comment: There's only ever one dict object (for each dict in the list). Assigning it to a new list doesn't create a second copy of it. Modifying it modifies the original.

Comment: Thanks deceze. Have solved problem by using  y = copy.deepcopy(lst[0]) to create a truly new dictionary.